# How to get value from enum in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, enums

I get a response from API and i deffine a enum like this

```
enum StatusEnum { EMPTY, STATUS, PURPLE }

final statusEnumValues = EnumValues({
  "کنسل شده": StatusEnum.EMPTY,
  "اتمام": StatusEnum.PURPLE,
  "در انتظار پرداخت": StatusEnum.STATUS
});
```

but when I use this in my code I get the error "The argument type "StatusEnum" can not be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
this my code that i use:

```
  Consumer<GetOrders>(
                    builder: (context, data, child) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: getOrders.allData.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      try {
                                        return Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                          children: [
                                            Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                              children: [
                                                Text(
                                                  data.allData[index].statuse,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontFamily:
                                                      "Vazir",fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        );
                                      } on Exception catch (_) {
                                        print('never reached');
                                        return null;
                                      }
                                  });
                    },
                  )
```

can anyone help mo to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried this? final statusEnumValues = EnumValues<StatusEnum>({

Comment: You can use StatusEnum.EMPTY.toString()

Answer (score 2):

**Update Dart 2.15:**

```
enum Status {
  failed,
  pending,
}
```

You can use `name` property on the enum.

```
String status = Day.failed.name; // 'failed'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will try
`StatusEnum.PURPLE.toString()`, you will get a string 'StatusEnum.PURPLE'.
For this purpose, of getting only value, I prefer and recommend using [enum_to_string](https://pub.dev/packages/enum_to_string) package. It allows to get enum value as a String, without your enum name, i.e. `YourEnum.value` -> `EnumToString.toString(YourEnum.value)` => `value`.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will describe the implementation of the enum:

```
enum Day {
  monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday
}

void validateDescribeEnum() {
  assert(Day.monday.toString() == 'Day.monday');
  assert(describeEnum(Day.monday) == 'monday');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer languages where Enums can have useful values, it helps them serve a dual purpose, so this has been annoying me for a bit.

I found a solution today.

I'm writing an cross-platform music player. One player (audio_players) works great on Android and iOS, but Windows has issues. Another, less-poilished (kplayers), seems to work on all platforms, but I really prefer audio_players.

Some of my app features don't work on the Web, so I wanted a `_playerMode` matching a `_playerModes` enum.

But then I wanted something simpler for which player to call in general controls. I didn't want two enums.

This is what I devised.

```
enum _playerModes { apFile, apWeb, kpFile, kpWeb }

extension pmExt on _playerModes {
  String getPlayer() {
    if (this == _playerModes.apFile || this == _playerModes.apWeb) {
      return "ap";
    } else {
      return "kp";
    }
  }
}
```

Elsewhere in my code, I can do `_playerMode.getPlayer()`

Now, I could have easily done something like

```
determinePlayerType(_playerModes pm) {
  if (pm == _playerModes.apFile || pm == _playerModes.apWeb) {
    return "ap";
  } else {
    return "kp";
  }
}
```

Also, for longer enums, you could do a map like

```
const Map<_playerModes, String> _pmMap = {_playerModes.apFile: "ap",
  ..}

extension pmExt on _playerModes {
  String? getPlayer() {
    return _pmMap[this];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Flutter 3.0 your enum could look like this:

```
enum StatusEnum {
  empty( "کنسل شده"),
  status("اتمام"),
  purple("در انتظار پرداخت");

  const StatusEnum(this.value);
  
  final String value;
}
```

And then to get the String value: `StatusEnum.purple.value`

More on new enums is [here](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/using-enums-like-a-pro-in-flutter-4563dde2e8a9).